# Generate LLVM bytecode using CMake

Tags: makefile, cmake, clang, llvm, llvm-clang

How can I compile a `C/C++` project to `LLVM` bytecode (`.bc` file) using a `makefile` and compiling with `clang`?

Comment: wllvm or gllvm (https://github.com/SRI-CSL/gllvm)